# Getting Two react components to speak to each other with 'google-maps-react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am still new to React, I have two components, one creates a map and the other lists places on the map, I am trying to find a way so that when one of the list items is clicked that the InfoWindow on the map pops up.

This is the Map Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

var  AllPlaces = [
  {
    "name" : "Pizza",
    "lat": "40.7589",
    "lng":"-73.9851",
  },

  {
    "name" : "Cookies",
    "lat": "40.7690",
    "lng":"-73.9952",
  }
]

class MapContainer extends Component {
state = {
showingInfoWindow: false,
activeMarker: {},
selectedPlace: {},
};

onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
this.setState({
  selectedPlace: props,
  activeMarker: marker,
  showingInfoWindow: true
 });

onMapClicked = (props) => {
if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
  this.setState({
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: null
  })
}
};

render() {
return (
  <div className = 'map-container' style={{marginleft:'250px'}}>
    <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}
      initialCenter = {{lat:40.7589, lng:-73.9851}}
      onClick={this.onMapClicked}>
      <Marker
        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
        title = {AllPlaces[0].name}
        name={AllPlaces[0].name}
        position = {{lat:AllPlaces[0].lat,lng:AllPlaces[0].lng}}/>
      <Marker
        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
        title = {AllPlaces[1].name}
        name={AllPlaces[1].name}
        position = {{lat:AllPlaces[1].lat,lng:AllPlaces[1].lng}}/>
      <InfoWindow
        onOpen={this.windowHasOpened}
        onClose={this.windowHasClosed}
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
        <div>
          <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
        </div>
      </InfoWindow>
    </Map>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
apiKey: 'AIzaSyC21SntdNn1vCb5VOAujCPIM7a9p5XkvRs'
})(MapContainer)
```

And this is the List Component

```
{import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GoogleApiWrapper, InfoWindow, Map, Marker } from 'google-maps- 
react';

var  AllPlaces = [
  {
    "name" : "Pizza",
    "lat": "40.7589",
    "lng":"-73.9851",
  },

  {
    "name" : "Cookies",
    "lat": "40.7690",
    "lng":"-73.9952",
  }
]

class ListPlaces extends Component {

CreateInputField = () => {
return <input
placeholder = "Search Nearby Places"
/>
}

findPlaces = () => {
return(
  <ol className='Places'>
    {AllPlaces.map((arrayItem, index)=>
      <li
      key = {index}
      className='Place'
      >{arrayItem.name}</li>
    )}
  </ol>
)
}

render() {
return(
  <div>
    <div className = 'sideMenu'>
      <div className = 'List'>
        <h1 className = 'title'> Places to Eat </h1>
        {this.CreateInputField()}
      </div>
      <div className = 'PlaceList'>
        {this.findPlaces()}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
}
export default ListPlaces
}
```

I have no idea how I can make it so that when one of the items in the list component are clicked that the correct InfoWindow will show.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method within the parent component which retrieves the clicked item information and stores them in its state. Then give the value of the state to the other component. Something like:

```
// Parent.js

class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        ...
        position: null;
    }

    ...

    setPosition = (position) => {
      this.setState({ position })
    }

    render () {
        return (
          <Fragment>
              <A position={this.state.position} />
              <B setPosition={this.setPosition} />
          </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

// B.js

class B extends Component {
  ...

  notifyParent = (item) => {
    this.props.setPosition(item)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
          {items && items.map(item => (
            <li onClick={() => this.notifyParent(item)}>
                {item.key}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```